# Crackle/Popping Sound When Playing Audio + Stuttering Video Games

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, hardware-failure, computer-building

I just built a PC:

- ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-H GAMING
- Intel i7 8700k
- EVGA Geforce GTX 1080 FTW 8 GB
- Corsair RMx Series, RM750x 750w
- Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB SSD
- Seagate 2 TB FireCuda Gaming SSHD
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2x8GB) DDR4 DRAM 3200 MHz
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Not currently OC'd, default specs.

Whenever I play audio (YouTube, foobar, VLC player, video games) I can hear a popping/crackling sound whenever I start or stop it. It's like the small crackle sound you hear when you plug in headphones/speakers. This also happens during playback, although not randomly – it's usually a specific part of the audio/video file that causes the popping. I can even find the particular "pop" spot and replay it.

Additionally, whenever I'm playing a video game I get random frame skips at random intervals. This happens in all my video games – WoW, Subnautica, Fallout 4, Dark Souls 3.

Originally I had the ASUS Prime z370-A which I thought to be the issue. But I replaced it with the ROG Strix and I can still hear the popping/crackling and the frame skips still happen.

Does anyone have experience with this issue? This is my first build over $1k and I'm very distressed that I cannot find the problem. Could it be the hard drives? RAM, maybe?

Comment: What is actually making sound? I'm assuming your gtx 1080 is the sound source. But what is it playing out of? Being able to replay a YouTube video and replicate it at certain spots says that the speakers/headphones/hdtv? are no longer responding to certain frequencies. Or it could be a khz sampling mismatch. I.e your outputting at frequencies your audio broadcasting device can't physically respond to. The frame skipping during games probably is unrelated, and should be asked as it's own question!

Comment: Yes, we need a few more details. Is audio going out through the 1080 or the audio plugs on the back of the MB? Your ROG has an S/PDIF optical port. Can you try that? That would certainly eliminate loose electrical connectors.